# Change 'Bibliography' word in Scriblib Autobib bibliography

Tags: latex, racket, bibliography, scribble

I have the following scribble document that uses a bibliography:

```
#lang scribble/base

@(require scriblib/autobib)

@(define-cite cite citet gen-bib)

This is a citation@cite[the-citation].

@(define the-citation
   (make-bib #:title "Hello"
             #:author "World"
             #:date "1337"))

@gen-bib[]
```

The document's result looks something like this:

[image: Scribble Document]

The bibliography section is title 'BIBLIOGRAPHY', but I would actually like it to be titled 'REFERENCES', is this possible with scribble, or do I have to drop into latex hacking?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with Scribble (or rather, `scriblib/autobib`).

The `gen-bib` function you used (defined with [`define-cite`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scriblib/autobib.html?q=define-cite#%28form._%28%28lib._scriblib%2Fautobib..rkt%29._define-cite%29%29)), has an option `#:sec-title`, that you can use to set the title for your bibliography. If you change that line to:

```
@gen-bib[#:sec-title "References"]
```

The you will get the same document, except for a 'REFERENCES' section rather than a 'BIBLIOGRAPHY' one.

[image: Document with References]

The code will look like:

```
#lang scribble/base

@(require scriblib/autobib)

@(define-cite cite citet gen-bib)

This is a citation@cite[the-citation].

@(define the-citation
   (make-bib #:title "Hello"
             #:author "World"
             #:date "1337"))

@gen-bib[#:sec-title "References"]
```

Comment: Looks like the name for this function has been changed and is now (Oct 2022) called `generate-bibliography`.